# How do plugins get executed automatically from wp-content?

Tags: plugins

Most plugins that are installed into /wp-content/plugins need to be activated. However, it seems that if you drop scripts directly into /wp-content (object-cache.php comes to mind) they are activated automatically.

How is this?

Answer (score 1):

I know, myself, using a multi site Wordpress install, plugins dropped into the mu-plugins folder (wp-content/mu-plugins/) are activated automatically.  In this case mu representing must use.

However, I am not 100% positive if this is dependent upon the type of install a single site blog install or multi site/network install.

I found an article outlining most of the information about mu and drop in plugins that I know [here](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/).

Additionally, if you are looking specifically for how these plugins are loaded I opened up /wp-admin/includes/plugin.php and found get_mu_plugins() on line 279.

Comment: **mu** stands for **must use**. It works in single site installations too.

Answer (score 1):

If WP_CACHE is set it expects in the wp-content folder the cache php file.

The way to disable the WordPress cache is to define another cache, also in the wp-content folder, called object-cache.php.

found google at the top: http://funcdoc.wordpress.com/2008/01/30/replacing-wordpress-object-caching/

So answer: no (almost) no plugins get executed from wp-content. to execute them automatically see the other answer on the drop ins.

Answer (score 0):

There is number of specially named files that get loaded automatically when present. They are called `Drop-ins` and are displayed in Plugins interface when present (since some recent WP versions).

[image]

They can be added by regular plugin or manually.

Note that this only works for specific files. Those that are not recognized as drop-in won't run automatically and will require activation as usual or placing them in `mu-plugins`.